# How work directives lifecycle sequence when one directive located inside another directive in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, angular6

In component I have two directive:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ng-parent]'
})
export class Parent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public ngOnInit(): void {           
        console.log('parent.directive:ngOnInit');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('parent.directive:ngAfterViewInit');
    }
}

@Directive({
    selector: '[ng-child]'
})
export class Child implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
    public ngOnInit(): void {           
        console.log('child.directive:ngOnInit');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log('child.directive:ngAfterViewInit');
    }
}
```

On `main.component` I use directives like this:

```
<div ngParent>
    <ng-template ngFor let-row [ngForOf]="arrRows">
        <div>
            <ng-template ngFor let-field [ngForOf]="arrFields">
                <div ngChild></div>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

Console display result init sequence:

```
main.component:ngOnInit
ng-parent.directive:ngOnInit
ng-parent.directive:ngAfterViewInit
main.component:ngAfterViewInit
ng-child.directive:ngOnInit
ng-child.directive:ngAfterViewInit
```

I simplify code. I guess probles is `ng-template` in `ng-template`. As I understand  lifecycle sequence should be different. I need result init lifecycle 
 directives sequence like this:

```
    main.component:ngOnInit
    ng-parent.directive:ngOnInit
    ng-child.directive:ngOnInit
    ng-child.directive:ngAfterViewInit
    ng-parent.directive:ngAfterViewInit
    main.component:ngAfterViewInit
```

Comment: Shouldn't be the case. Can you add a stackblitz for the same. I am getting the correct order when I implement the same.

Comment: Was working at 4.0.0 version now not. My Angular 6.1.7 version now.

Comment: Find error: ifarrRows or arrFields not ready (for example mapping delay) ng-template init after component lifecycle sequence fin.